# How to render children in Qwik?

Tags: qwik

In React, I had this component:

```
const Title = ({ children }) => {
    return <h2>{children}</h2>
}

export default Title
```

And I could easily use it as `<Title>Something</Title>`

In Qwik, I can create the same component:

```
import { component$ } from '@builder.io/qwik'

const Title = component$(({ children }) => {
    return <h2>{children}</h2>
})

export default Title
```

But `<Title>Something</Title>` does not work. Even `<Title children='Something' />` does not work. But if I change the prop name to `text`, then `<Title text='Something' />` works.

However, the ability to nest components and reuse them under a special name is a must in real-world applications.

How can I render children in Qwik?

Comment: There is a perfect reason Qwik not use children instead it use Slot because Qwik is lazy loaded framework that do not download javascript code eagerly it gives Qwik child component freedom to rerender without the wait of its parent.

Answer (score 6):

Qwik uses Slot instead of children

```
import { component$, Slot } from '@builder.io/qwik'

const Title = component$(() => {
    return <h2><Slot /></h2>
})

export default Title
```

See https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/projection/